# Any way to get a cheaper train ticket from Winnipeg to Churchill?

Tags: trains, canada, churchill, manitoba, winnipeg

With ViaRail in Canada, there's a main route across the country, and a northern route from Winnipeg directly north to Churchill, in Manitoba.

With the trans-Canada route, there are [frequent deals](http://www.viarail.ca/en/deals) offering massive discounts if you're flexible with your travel dates.  However, there doesn't seem to be an option to apply deals to the Winnipeg-Churchill route.

Are there ever discounts on this route? Is there a way to reduce the price of an economy class seat?

Comment: All I can find are age discounts.
http://www.ehow.com/how_2023325_train-winnipeg-churchill.html

Comment: Indeed I found sad that only a few routes have these good discounts. Did you consider the Canrailpass? It's expensive but the price of a round-trip Winnipeg-Churchill is too, so if you plan to travel across the country it might be worth the price. http://reservia.viarail.ca/discountpass/ViewPassFareByType.aspx?tpass=1&l=en

Comment: @Vince yes I had found it and am thinking about taking it up.  Actually, you might consider putting it as an answer - it is a valid way to get a 'cheaper' ticket, if you're doing a lot of train travel, and many tourists would be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note: Posting as an answer on Mark's suggestion

Indeed, the deals of ViaRail unfortunately only cover a few itineraries, and usually only between major stops.

There are few ways to get a good deal with ViaRail. The main one I know of, for cross-country tourism, is the [Canrailpass](http://www.viarail.ca/en/fares-and-packages/rail-passes/canrailpass-system). It allows you to travel for 21 days and/or 7 one-way trips (whichever comes first). The pass costs from $630 to $1100 (plus tax)

In your case, the trip from Winnipeg to Churchill (round-trip) is worth $300-370 when bought at full price.

As I suppose you don't live in Winnipeg, you can also use the train to get there. It is purely hypothetical, but then, a round-trip from Toronto is worth over $400, and the pass becomes pretty competitive. Especially as you will probably visit Churchill in low season (I heard best time is around end of October), so the pass price is comparable to the round-trip price from Toronto, so you can add some free train rides to your agenda.

To add a bit about the pass conditions : you are allowed 1 stopover for each of the 7 one-way trips. With the pass, you can only have access to seats with supersaver/discounted fares, so book ahead (but you can cancel any trip before train departure).

Comment: I did the Canrailpass back in '92 and included the Winnipeg-Churchill route. Even paid on the spot for a bed on the Churchill-Winnipeg leg if I remember right. (They had been booked out on the way up.) I see the rules have changed since.